# ¿Cómo iterar una lista con otra lista?

Tags: python, pandas, bucles, dataframe

Tengo un Data Frame donde vienen (en una columna) unos 2000 teléfonos de 10 dígitos, necesito saber de que regiones del país se están registrando mas, por lo que se me ocurrió usar las ladas (los primeros 3 dígitos) como indicador, tengo otra lista con las ladas del país, pero no se como plantear un ciclo for en donde se las ladas recorran la lista de los telefonos y como resultado de una tabla donde diga el número de veces que la lada está presente en la columna Telefonos

```
for df['Lada'] in df['Telefono']:
    if df['Telefono'].str.startswith(df['Lada']).value_counts()
```

Había pensando en algo así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si únicamente deseas saber cuantos teléfonos hay en cada "Lada", lo puedes hacer muy fácilmente con [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html)

Como no pusiste tus datos, cree un ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Tel':['1231231230', '1234564560', '1237897890', '4561231231', '4564564561', '7891234560']})
resultado = df.groupby([df['Tel'].str[:3]]).count()
print(resultado)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
     Tel
Tel     
123    3
456    2
789    1
```

Las columnas de tipo `string` tienen un accesor `str` que puede segmentarse utilizando `slices` por lo que `df['Tel'].str[:3]` devuelve los primeros 3 caracteres de cada celda.

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Comment: Sobre la nota que mencionas  hay una respuesta muy interesante en SO en inglés sobre las formas de iterar sobre la filas en un dataframe de pandas https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/1436666  que puede complementar lo que mencionas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @friveroll, acabo de leerla y está muy completa, yo normalmente agrego esa nota cuando encuentro preguntas que utilizan cilos con `pandas`, en parte para hacer conciencia y porque no es tan largo como la respuesta que comentas ya que eso convertiría mis respuestas en tesis jaja.